# Server Error 500 for json_encode

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on PHP project and when I try my code in localhost it works properly. But when I try it on production server I get 500 server error. I don't have access to error_reporting in php.ini. So I cannot find the error. Is there any other way to find the error or what's wrong with it?

**start_shift_json.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'include/DB_Driver_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Driver_Functions ();

// json response array
$response = array (
        "error" => FALSE 
);

if (isset ( $_GET ['driver_id'] ) && isset ( $_GET ['odor_meter'] ) && isset ( $_GET['expenses'] ) && isset ( $_GET ['vehicle_registreation'] )) {
    $driver_id = $_GET ['driver_id'];
    $odor_meter = $_GET ['odor_meter'];
    $expenses = $_GET ['expenses'];
    $vehicle_registreation = $_GET ['vehicle_registreation'];

    $result = $db->storeShift ( $driver_id, $odor_meter, $expenses, $vehicle_registreation );

    if ($result != false) {
        // use is found
        $response ["error"] = FALSE;
        $response ["id"] = $result ["id"];
        $response ["driver_id"] = $result ["driver_id"];
        $response ["start_time"] = $result ["start_time"];
        $response ["odor_meter"] = $result ["odor_meter"];
        $response ["expenses"] = $result ["expenses"];
        $response ["vehicle_registration"] = $result ["vehicle_registration"];
        echo json_encode ( $response );
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response ["error"] = TRUE;
        $response ["error_msg"] = "Error occured in database layer. Error:29!";
        echo json_encode ( $response );
    }

} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response ["error"] = TRUE;
    $response ["error_msg"] = "Required parameters missing!";
    echo json_encode ( $response );
}
```

**DB_Driver_Functions.php**

```
public function storeShift($driver_id, $odor_meter, $expenses, $vehicle_registreation){
        $start_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO shifts(driver_id, start_time, odor_meter, expenses, vehicle_registration) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $driver_id, $start_time, $odor_meter, $expenses, $vehicle_registreation);

        $storeResult = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close(); 

        // check for successful store
        if ($storeResult) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM shifts WHERE driver_id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param ( "s", $driver_id );
            $stmt->execute ();
            $result = $stmt->get_result ()->fetch_assoc ();
            $stmt->close ();

            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And Here is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shifts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `driver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `odor_meter` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expenses` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vehicle_registration` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `driver_id` (`driver_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The strange thing is when I initialize the remote url with parameters it insert the data, but I don't get $result json. Instead I get 500 server error.

[image]

Comment: Run your code per line.

Comment: The error should be written to the server's HTTP error log. If you're using a standard LAMP setup, the error log you want is probably at /var/log/apache2/error_log (or somewhere in that vicinity). If you don't have access to this directly, you should be able to ask your sysadmin or manager for it.

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');` to your code.